# Looking for an elegant proof for $e^{jn\pi} = (-1)^n e^{-jn\pi}$

Tags: complex-numbers, eulers-number-e

I want to prove that

$$e^{jn\pi} = (-1)^n e^{-jn\pi} \quad (1)$$

---

**My attempt**

$$ e^{jn\pi} = (-1)^n e^{-jn\pi} \iff ln(e^{jn\pi}) = ln((-1)^n) + ln(e^{-jn\pi} ) \iff jn\pi = jn\pi - jn\pi$$
$$\iff n = 0 $$
$$\text{But this should be true }  \forall n, \text{therefore something went wrong  here}$$

---

I am very confident that there is a more beautiful proof based on Euler's formula but I can't find it.
What I've also tried is:

$$e^{jn\pi} = cos(n\pi) + j sin(n\pi) = (-1)^n + j sin(n\pi) = ?  $$

Comment: The claim is false (assuming of course $n\in\Bbb Z$ and $j^2=-1$).

Comment: $e^{jn\pi}$ is always a real number, so it must equal its conjugate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is false. Notice that

$$(e^{j \pi})^n = (-1)^n$$

Then your statement is

$$(-1)^n = (-1)^n (-1)^{-n}$$

However, the right-hand-side simplifies to $(-1)^0 = 1$, so the statement can only be true for $n$ even at best. For instance, [letting $n=3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28e%5E%28i+pi+3%29%29+%3B+%28-1%29%5E3+e%5E%28-i+3+pi%29) produces the statement $-1 = 1$, though at least [$n=4$ is true](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28e%5E%28i+pi+4%29%29+%3B+%28-1%29%5E4+e%5E%28-i+4+pi%29).